# cmake: Why is CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P empty on Apple Silicon macOS?

Tags: macos, arm, cmake, apple, arm64

A promise of `cmake` is its cross-platform compatibility. So why does the following code does not print any value for `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P` on Apple Silicon macOS?

File `sizeofvoid.cmake`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
message(STATUS "size of void pointer: ${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}")
```

Command:

```
cmake -P sizeofvoid.cmake
```

Output:

```
-- size of void pointer:
```